# Ran rebase in wrong direction?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-revert

I have `master` and a `search` branch. I've been making all these changes in my `search` branch, and committing to it. Then I'd run `git push origin search`.

I have been doing this for months, but now I'd like to have these changes reflect in `master`, basically catch `master` up to `search`.

I read responses here indicating that `rebase` may be the answer I'm looking for. Upon executing `git checkout master` and then `git rebase master search`, there were a bunch of conflicts that I had to resolve. Once resolved, I finished with a final `git rebase --continue` and it completed.

However, now I'm seeing the status for `search` is up to date, but `master` shows a status message saying **"Your branch and 'origin/search' have diverged"** and suggesting that I do a `git pull` from master to merge the remote branch (search?) into mine (master?). Upon reading some of the answers here, I'm still a bit confused over this.

Question 1: Did I run the rebase command backward; should it have been `git rebase search master`?

Question 2: What should I do now? Can I do a rollback (git revert)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have performed your rebase correctly. To verify, see if the parent commit of your `search` branch matches the tip of the master branch (`git rev-parse search~` and `git rev-parse master`)

You are seeing that message because your local `search` branch has diverged from the remote version of the `search` branch...meaning that they no longer have a common commit...even though the content between the two branches is likely almost the same (minus the conflict resolution changes).

This message is entirely expected...you have (for very good reason) re-written the history of your `search` branch, giving it a different base commit.

So, if you are wanting to push your latest `search` changes to your remote `search` branch you will need to do a "force push" like this:

```
git push --force origin search
```

Git is forcing you to do a force push because if other developers were also working off of the `search` branch they would also become diverged.

But, after you merge into `master` it won't matter that your `search` branch has been changed in this way and the folks using the `master` branch will be happy that you improved the clarity of the overall commit history by rebasing before you merge to the common branch.

Here is more information about force pushing: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push--f

Comment: Thanks, but currently master isn't seeing my latest changes when I view the master branch from a browser. Also, will I need to the the forced push prior to the pull as it suggests?

Comment: To get your local `master` branch up to date with what's on the server you will need to pull (on `master`, not `search`). The forced push is only for the `search` branch. After you perform the rebase, you will be able to do a typical (fast-forward) merge onto the master branch and then do a normal (non-force) push there. The only branch that is becoming diverged in this process is `search`, not `master`.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to revert back to right before I started this mess with `rebase`. I did a `git reset --hard ` and the files look okay in this `search` branch. Now, how can I get `master` to where `search` is?

Comment: Here is some steps. First, let's get your `search` branch rebased on top of master: `git checkout search; git rebase master;` Fix the conflicts. `git push --force origin search`. Now, let's update master: `git checkout master; git merge search;` And finally: `git push origin master`

Comment: Yep, this was it. Thanks!